# Why doesn't my regular expression work in NotePad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

Why doesn't `<example regular expression here>` work in NotePad++?

Comment: Given that the Notepad++ online help [is just plain wrong on this](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/searching/normal-search), I think this is a worthwhile topic, although it could, of course, be edited to actually include content ;)

Comment: @Daniel, I don't think it's right to just copy the whole page - but a summary is likely to omit some reader's particular problem - there are so many little quirks.  Thoughts?  Do you want to add another answer that reflects what you think should be here?

Comment: To the down-voter: what's the problem?  I'm trying to provide an instant, no-waiting-required answer to all of the questions of this ilk.  Is this bad?

Comment: You cannot make a question community wiki.  If you believe a question should be CW, flag it for moderator attention using the free-text box.  See [this Meta Stack Overflow question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better) and [waffles's answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192) for more information.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close. I just don't understand what's the real question here. **Why** Notepad++ doesn't have it? Who knows? Lazyness? A bug? Shouldn't the real question be **how** to get such a feature? The fact that you self-answered makes me think it's the latter. Which isn't a problem, at all, but kind of confusing.

Comment: @slhck - I understand - do what you think best.  You may be confused- look at the link in the answer.  Notepad++ _has_ regex - it's just very quirky.  My thought was that many people end up confused by this (certainly I've been multiple times).  I thought it would be good to have a post that a Google search will likely hit and clue the searcher that there's a generic issue.  The alternative was to go through all the [notepad++][regex] posts and add a comment to each one where this is relevant and hasn't been said already - that's more than I'm willing to volunteer for!

Comment: There are quite a few "why doesn't this regex work in N++" questions on SO: to name a few: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4815351/92837 http://stackoverflow.com/q/3971052/92837 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2692392/92837  The documentation [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators) suggests what it can and cannot do

Comment: Shame on the closers for what is obviously a real question, it may be broad but it will obviously be useful for those in the future looking for answers on this.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Since when do we keep questions open based on usefulness? This question is really rhetorical, you can't expect any other answer than `because it's not there`; nothing that we do helps the user use Notepad++ or his computer in a better way so this is not our terrain. As Sathya referred, if one wants to understand the internals then Stack Overflow or perhaps Programmers is the site where you can find more information. But as there are enough duplicates, there is no point in migrating sand...

Comment: @EdStaub: You should definitely raise this issue on the Notepad++ Forums; or, perhaps someone else is interested in doing so. It would be of a bigger benefit if the regular expression engine was improved to support this, or the documentation were adjusted to make a note of this fact. Not to hide it away in an answer on a Q&A site, not everyone searches for "doesn't work"...

Comment: (I'm the OP) I've actually come to agree with the close decision.  The reason I did this in the first place was because the Windows help for notepad++ is deficient.  But I forgot what I think should be the _real_ test - the Google test.  And a search for "notepad++ regex" or "notepad++ regular expression" is Lucky - first pick is accurate documentation.  So there's no point in replicating it.  Sorry to waste your time!!!

Comment: Actually, one of the end goals of these sites is to be the repository for all (on-topic) Q&A, so that searches will lead people here, to a Q&A site with a superior format.  @Tom is incorrect on his expectations of an answer, having spent many days sometimes looking for correct documentation, I know how hard it is to actually find if you don't get lucky in your search terms.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: That's not the case here, as Ed noted these are I'm Feeling Lucky results. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5112757/how-to-get-this-correct-regex-to-work-in-notepad) already serves the same purpose, there are other Stack Overflow questions on more specific Notepad++ RegExp issues and as said you can directly find the documentation. So, I don't really see the point in reopening this question. The real effort is actually asking Notepad++ rather than Super User, I'd rather like an actual fix to the program/documentation than a fountain of rhetorical duplicates...

Answer (score 4):

NotePad++ is missing many common regex features, and some others have unusual syntax.

The *correct* [documentation for regular expressions](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTERegEx.html) is a bit hard to find, and as Daniel points out, there's even documentation that says they meet Posix, which isn't right.

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators is a link to unsupported regex expressions