# Notepad++ Find & Replace (with regex) issue

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I'm going crazy on a weird issue, I've been trying to find this text:

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[procName] (@EMI_ID numeric(8), @ESYNTH_ID numeric(8), @FLD_ID numeric(8), @SYNTH_ID numeric(8)) As
```

And I use this regex:

```
CREATE Proc \[dbo\]\.\[(.+)\] \(@EMI_ID numeric\(8\), @ESYNTH_ID numeric\(8\), @FLD_ID numeric\(8\), @SYNTH_ID numeric\(8\)\) As
```

In the "find"
However this won't work, BUT if I try to match with just this regex (same as above but without the last stored proc parameter):

```
CREATE Proc \[dbo\]\.\[(.+)\] \(@EMI_ID numeric\(8\), @ESYNTH_ID numeric\(8\), @FLD_ID numeric\(8\),
```

It works without problem.

I have also tried to use TextFX's Find and Replace to no avail.
Please help, madness consumes me!

Thanks ;)

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/339658/why-doesnt-my-regular-expression-work-in-notepad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yup your regex is correct.

but notepad++ seems to be in my tests limited to 103 char, regex string.

`CREATE Proc \[dbo]\.\[(.+)\] \(@EMI_ID numeric\(8\), @ESYNTH_ID numeric\(8\), @FLD_ID numeric\(8\), @S`

tested and found multi in text file i created.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Although not the nicest regex, your first regex should match the target string. This is a fault with Notepad++.

I find [A Programmer's Notepad](http://www.pnotepad.org/) to be a better text editor, and in fact your regex works in this program,